# Чтение десятичных чисел из файла

Tags: c++, qml

Здравстуйте. Имеется файл с числами в 10 СС. Пример:
5 10 15 16
2 3 44 55
Нужно считать файл построчно и вывести данные построчно в 2 СС в одну строку. Старые данные данные должны удалиться.
Как правильно считать данные и во что их записать?
С переводом между СС я разобрался.
Как переведенные данные записать.
Пишу на с++  в QML.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Оч. здор. задавать вопр. сокр. — какая эконом. только на "2СС"!!

Comment: Бсь дл ршн нжн бдт мнг смвлв. Рстчтльств!